# How to highlight, searched word in PDF reader?

Tags: iphone, pdf, pdf-reader, quartz-core

In PDF reading application is being developed and using `QuartzCore`(VFR) framework PDF reading is being achieved. Now what is needed to be implement is to **highlight** the text, which is being searched by the user. How to achieve it?

NOTE: I have went through **FAST PDF KIT**, but been unable to get any thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten.