# Highlighting a string in a pdf iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

I'm developing a book `app.My` client has provided all the contents of `pdf`.

I have already implemented all the contents of `pdf` to book.

But he wanted to highlight a text in that pdf.

The user would like the text to allow for highlighting (like if you're reading a paper book).

Is this possible? Can anyone help me on this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dupes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661933/how-to-highlight-searched-word-in-pdf-reader
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444285/search-and-highlight-text-in-pdf-rendered-in-uiview

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes.. depends on a bit hacking and other things, for example fonts used in the PDF. Have a look at PdfKitten, their demo project can find text in a PDF and highlight it. That should give you a first pointer on how to highlight. If you want to the user to highlight with the touches you would need to be able to transform locations of touches into the PDF to determine where exactly the user touched, but it should be possible.

Comment: FastPDFKit may be helpful as well